# Exclude array items from their counterparts

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a tournament that pits each fighter against 5 others. For this I have two arrays, playerArray and opponentArray, each containing the same six character types.

When matching them up in the tournament, I'd like to prevent them from fighting their own type, that is for example, I don't want Rogue vs Rogue matchups.

Is this done somehow with splice?

```
var playerArray:Array = ["Fighter", "Ranger", "Wizard", "Rogue", "Cleric", "Sorcerer"];
var opponentArray:Array = ["Fighter", "Ranger", "Wizard", "Rogue", "Cleric", "Sorcerer"];

charSel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, matchups);

function matchups(event:MouseEvent){
for (a = 0; a < 6; a++){        // for each character
    trace ("\n=== " + playerArray[a] + " fights ===\n");
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++){    // fight each opponent
        trace (playerArray[a] + " vs " + opponentArray[b]);
    }
}
```

}

Brand new to this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (a = 0; a < playerArray.length; a++){        // for each character
    trace ("\n=== " + playerArray[a] + " fights ===\n");
    for (b = 0; b < opponentArray.length; b++){    // fight each opponent
        if(playerArray[a] != opponentArray[b])
            trace (playerArray[a] + " vs " + opponentArray[b]);
    }
}
```

You can avoid the hard coding part. Instead use the `array.length` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use **String Comparison** as a quick solution,

I have updated your code,

```
function matchups(event:MouseEvent) {

   for (a = 0; a < 6; a++){  // for each character

        trace ("\n=== " + playerArray[a] + " fights ===\n");

        for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {    // fight each opponent

            trace (playerArray[a] + " vs " + opponentArray[b]);

            //This is added part (Comparing a String)
            if(String(playerArray[a]) == String(opponentArray[b]))
            {
                  trace("Opponents are of same type.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up vote if you like any answer. It helps the community.

Comment: I tried, but it seems I cannot upvote until I have 15 rep. I'm new here so I will earn some rep and come back :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you skip if playerArray and opponentArray value are same in iteration.

```
for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{        
    trace ("\n=== " + playerArray[a] + " fights ===\n");

    for (var b = 0; b < 6; b++) //Note here 5 to 6 better you length property of Array like opponentArray.length
    {    
        if(playerArray[a] == opponentArray[b])
            continue;

        trace (playerArray[a] + " vs " + opponentArray[b]);
    }
}
```